# Relacionar coluna de uma tabela com todos os registros de outra

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho 2 tabelas, `posts` e `posts_images`, a tabela `post` possui os campos **id**, **title**, **category**, e **images**, e a tabela `posts_images` possui: **post_id**, **img_url** e etc.., gostaria de relacionar o campo **images** da tabela `posts` com todos os registros da tabela `posts_images` que possuam o mesmo **post_id** do campo **id** da tabela `posts`

Resumindo, tabela **POSTS**

```
id,
title,
category,
images => todos os registros da tabela `posts_images` com o post_id = id
```

como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Como assim realcionar? Em uma busca?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que sua estrutura de dados seja algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_post
(
   id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
   title TEXT NOT NULL,
   category TEXT NOT NULL
 );

CREATE TABLE tb_post_image
(
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_post BIGINT NOT NULL,
  url TEXT NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE tb_post_image ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_post) REFERENCES tb_post(id);
```

Contendo dados similares a isso:

```
-- POST #1
INSERT INTO tb_post ( id, title, category ) VALUES ( 1, 'Garota de Ipanema', 'Musica' );

-- POST #2
INSERT INTO tb_post ( id, title, category ) VALUES ( 2, 'Noite na Taverna', 'Literatura' );
INSERT INTO tb_post_image ( id, id_post, url ) VALUES ( 1, 2, 'noite1.jpg');
INSERT INTO tb_post_image ( id, id_post, url ) VALUES ( 2, 2, 'noite2.jpg');

-- POST #3
INSERT INTO tb_post ( id, title, category ) VALUES ( 3, 'Nao Sei Quantas Almas Tenho', 'Conto' );
INSERT INTO tb_post_image ( id, id_post, url ) VALUES ( 3, 3, 'alma1.jpg');
INSERT INTO tb_post_image ( id, id_post, url ) VALUES ( 4, 3, 'alma2.jpg');
```

Sua consulta pode ser feita assim:

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.title,
  img.id,
  img.url
FROM
  tb_post AS p
LEFT JOIN
  tb_post_image AS img ON ( img.id_post = p.id )
ORDER BY
  p.id,
  img.id;
```

Saída:

```
| id |                       title |     id |        url |
|----|-----------------------------|--------|------------|
|  1 |           Garota de Ipanema | (null) |     (null) |
|  2 |            Noite na Taverna |      1 | noite1.jpg |
|  2 |            Noite na Taverna |      2 | noite2.jpg |
|  3 | Nao Sei Quantas Almas Tenho |      3 |  alma1.jpg |
|  3 | Nao Sei Quantas Almas Tenho |      4 |  alma2.jpg |
|  3 | Nao Sei Quantas Almas Tenho |      5 |  alma3.jpg |
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0b7d9/1

**EDIT**

Se o intento é agrupar os registros de imagem em uma *array*, você pode fazer uma consulta como:

```
SELECT
     p.title,
     p.category,
     array_agg(img.url) AS array
FROM
     tb_post AS p
LEFT JOIN
    tb_post_image AS img ON ( img.id_post = p.id )
WHERE
     p.id = 3
GROUP BY
     p.title,
     p.category;
```

Saída:

```
|                       title | category |                         array |
|-----------------------------|----------|-------------------------------|
| Nao Sei Quantas Almas Tenho |    Conto | alma1.jpg,alma2.jpg,alma3.jpg |
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0b7d9/30

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou, estou usando isso no PHP, sabe me dizer como eu faço para a respota do mysql retornar num formato array com o campo url? no lugar do nome das imagens, seria url => array('noite1.jpg', 'noite2.jpg'....)

Comment: como se vários posts pudessem "apontar" para a mesma imagem

Comment: algo assim: https://prnt.sc/jej3m0